# Response to CORS preflight has HTTP status code 405

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cors, preflight

This is pretty much a known standard error but unable to fix the same using existing Stackoverflow posts.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://myserver.com/context/
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check:
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.
>   Origin 'https://www.otherwebsite.com' is therefore not allowed access.
>   The response had HTTP status code 405.

Following is the code I have -

```
function setHeader(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
}

var url = "https://myserver.com/context/";
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET', dataType:'json',
    success: function(data) {
        _this.question(data.question);
        _this.questionId(data.questionId);
        _this.choices(data.choices);
    }, error: function() {
        console.log("ERROR in getting microquestion");
    },
    beforeSend: setHeader
});
```

Comment: Reading the error message: "_No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present __on the requested resource__._"

Comment: I just realized what error was trying to point out. The issue was on the server side. that's what "requested resource" meant. Thanks to @sideshowbarker who explicitly pointed that out. Upvoting both of you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *“Response to preflight request… had HTTP status code 405.”* message indicates, to start, the `https://myserver.com/context/` endpoint needs to be configured to handle `OPTIONS` requests correctly—even if it may already be set to send the right CORS headers back for “normal” requests.

For more details about what’s happening, you can read the *How to avoid the CORS preflight* section of the answer at *[No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource—when trying to get data from a REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe/43881141#43881141)* — but the gist of it is, minimally, the server must respond to `OPTIONS` requests with a `2xx` success status code.